# How to attach new object around a round surface

Tags: modeling

[image]

I already have the head model. What's a nice way of doing the beard as a new object around the rounded face. Also how can I add texture similar to image without sculpting.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do it, one simple would be to duplicate the head mesh area where the beard is supposed to grow, draw the lines of the beard shapes with the knife tool (here it's a roughly try) then extrude twice, give it a *Subdivision Surface*, rework with additional edges, etc...

[image]